# Hive Date and Week Functions Migration From Greenplum Query

Tags: hive, hiveql, greenplum

Could you please help me as below statement , i want to migrate from Greenplum to HiveSQL. kindly help me.

```
(date_trunc('week',idate) - INTERVAL '1 week')::DATE date_from
((date_trunc('week',idate) - INTERVAL '1 week')::DATE + '6 days'::INTERVAL)::DATE
date_trunc('week',idate)::DATE
```

note: idate is i have to parse the argument like 2021-02-20

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to

1. find start of week then use `select next_day(date_sub(current_date, 7), 'MON')`
2. add 1 week to the date then use `select current_date + interval 7 day`
3. convert date to string then use `select  to_date(current_date )`

Now, from your code, it seems, you are looking for start of week and then deducting 1 week from that.
`(date_trunc('week',idate) - INTERVAL '1 week')`
This can be re-written in hive like below.

```
next_day(date_sub(current_date, 7), 'MON') - interval 7 day
```

I assumed Monday is your start of week. Please validate the SQL before using it.

Comment: i have migrated,plz validate :  (date_trunc('week',idate) - INTERVAL '1 week')::DATE -->>  cast(trunc(next_day(date_sub(current_date, 7), 'MON')) as date)  plz help me

Comment: This `next_day(date_sub(current_date, 7), 'MON')` will give datetime. you do nto have to cast it again. can you pls share your sql and exact error.